# Storing new line in database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to store some content with new line in database(mysql). But when I retrieve the data all of the data is merged and no new line is shown. 
For Example:
I am storing data through a text box.The data is:
First Hi

Second Hello

But when I retrieve it shows:

First HiSecond Hello

I want the output to be same as input(in new line)
Is there any function in php which can be used to store a new line (as /n or any other character) and then again convert that character into new line.

Comment: look at your html source when viewing the output; you'll see the linebreaks alright. You need to do this in php/html to view it on your screen.

Comment: Yes you are right there is a new line in source code of Html. But why it is not being shown in the output?

Comment: This looks like an output problem. Newlines are not equivalent to `<br/>` in HTML.

Comment: Hint: [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: So what can be done to convert new line to <br> in html?

Comment: and there you have it; as per what @tadman said, is basically what I told you HN

Comment: `while($row=(..fetch..){ echo $row['x'] . "<br>"; }` is one way. Otherwise, use what Tadman said.

Comment: nl2br function worked.. I ma getting the right output